# Case MySql retornando tipo blob

Tags: mysql, blob, case

Criei uma query de busca no MySQL e utilizando `case` dentro dela.
O problema é que ao retornar o valor da coluna que é do tipo inteiro, o valor vem com a resposta `blob`.

Segue o SELECT com imagem do resultado da query abaixo:

```
select 
max(b.sequencia),
case 
    when b.sequencia is null then '0'
    else max(b.sequencia)
end as Max 
from
    cad_tramitacao b 
where
    b.ficha = '187080' and b.arquivo = 'M' and b.incidente = "0";
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: se em vez de colocar '0' coloque 0? ou seja sem aspas simples ?

Comment: o problema é quando cai no else, onde ele vai dar o valor maior da coluna

Comment: b.sequencia é qual tipo ?

Comment: não acredito, alterei as aspas pra fazer um teste mesmo assim e deu certo

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo a dica do @virgilio Novic, apenas retirei as aspas do '0' e funcionou perfeitamente.